# Add class to input when model value not found in select items

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I would like to make a directive for an input element, which checks against the a corresponding `datalist` and adds a class if the value is not in `datalist`.

Since the `list` attribute is the `id` of corresponding `datalist`, I was using this:

```
app.directive('listCheck', function() {
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var options = document.querySelectorAll("#"+attrs.list+">option[ng-repeat]");
            //used as this since the list shouldn't change...
            console.log(options);    // <- return []
            //although the querySelector is all right
            //[ng-repeat] is used to remove the void options
        }
    }
});
```

And the HTML looks like:

```
<input list="dataMatter" ng-model="hourBox.matter">
<datalist id="dataMatter">
    <option ng-repeat="matter in Matter" value="{{matter.short}}">{{matter.name}}</option>
    <option value="(anything)">New matter</option>
</datalist>
```

As it seems, I need to defer the directive initialization until after the compilation is done, but I don't really want to use the $timeout for that (I may need to if there is no way around). Please let me know if there is a way to defer this.

Comment: You can add an attribute directive to your `ng-repeat` element which checks for `$last` on its scope so you know it has finished loading, then communicate that to your directive in whatever way you choose.

Comment: @MarcKline I am extremely new to directives, this is my first one. Please could you show me a bit more what you are talking about? Maybe as an separate answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite my previous comment suggesting a way to accomplish what you were looking to do in the strictest of senses, I'd like to suggest an improvement that might help you accomplish the same thing in a way that is more appropriate for Angular.

Instead of using the DOM to check the value of your `input` box against the values of the `select` options, which will require a hack-ish solution, you should compare the model of the input against the options data as it's stored in its original data structure.

**Data in controller:**

```
$scope.colors = [
    { name: 'Red' },
    { name: 'Orange' },
    { ... }
];
```

**Directive:**

```
.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      items: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'my-directive.html',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      scope.checkValue = function(search){
        // directive scope function which checks search
        // value against items array
      };
    }
  }
})
```

**Directive template:**

```
<div>
  <input type="text" ng-model="search" ng-change="checkValue(search)" ng-class="{notfound: notfound}" />
  <select ng-options="item.name for item in items" ng-model="selection">
    <option value>Choose an option</option>  
  </select>
</div>
```

**index.html:**

```
<my-directive items="colors"></my-directive>
```

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lRmUNZLp4beBYKf2iZSW?p=preview)

In summary, the [`ng-change`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) directive on the search `input` box triggers a directive scope method which compares the value against all of your data items for a match. If it doesn't find one, the [`ng-class`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) directive causes the `notfound` class to appear on the element.

As a rule, when writing an Angular app and you find yourself reaching to the DOM for the existence of elements, you'll find a better solution elsewhere. Workarounds using the DOM should be rare or non-existent in your code.

I'm hoping that my code (and [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lRmUNZLp4beBYKf2iZSW?p=preview)) provide you with a template to make changes to yours. If there are problems with this solution, let me know in the comments. If you have general questions about applying it to your code, feel free to contact me privately.